# Angular ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: form component code image]

[image: save method code image]

I created a form and I want to save the data in this form, I use the save method for this, but it gives such an error, how can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post actual code and not just screen shots of code. Also, you don't provide enough code or enough of the error message for anyone to help you. This is a very generic error and the details you provide doesn't allow anyone to really help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective first I suggest avoid using both formControlName and ngModel on the same input tag, you can make use of formControlName only by assigning a name linked to a FormGroup

Here is a sample example on how you can archieve what you want:

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="postForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="title">
    <button (click)="submit()">Save</button>
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  postForm: FormGroup;
  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createPostForm();
  }

  submit(): void {
    for (const i in this.postForm.controls) {
      this.postForm.controls[i].markAsDirty();
      this.postForm.controls[i].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
    if (this.postForm.valid) {
        // Submit to server... 
    }
  }

  /** Create postform instance */
  createPostForm(): void {
    this.postForm = this.fb.group({
      title: [null, Validators.required],
      content: '',
    
    });
  }

}
```

Also I can see you tried to check if a post already exist then create new one or update details, I suggest implement that logic on the backend, you can utilize options such as UpdateOrCreate on your database by passing a post id into your params or body and check if it's null then create or if its present create a new post, It can make your code maintainable.